# Extending jQuery in SPFx Web Part

Tags: jquery, spfx-webparts

I've used the jQuery plugin [jOrgChart](https://github.com/wesnolte/jOrgChart) with success in a SharePoint add-in by simply referencing the file and making the call, i.e.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jOrgChart.js"></script>
...
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("#org").jOrgChart();
});
```

Now I want to use the same plugin in a SPFx webpart. What have is:

```
import * as jQuery from "jquery";
import "jqueryui";
import "jorgchart";
//  also tried with the same result:
//  require("jorgchart");
...
let jOrgChart:any = require("./Scripts/jOrgChart.js");
...
jQuery("#org").jOrgChart({ chartElement: "#chart", dragAndDrop: false });
```

my `json.config` file includes:

```
"externals": {
"jquery": { 
    "path": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js",
    "globalName": "jquery"
},
"jqueryui":{
    "path": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js",
    "globalName": "jquery",
    "globalDependencies": ["jquery"]
},
"jorgchart": {
    "path": "./Scripts/jOrgChart.js",
    "globalName": "jquery",
    "globalDependencies": ["jqueryui"]
}
},
```

but I get the build TypeScript error: `Property 'jOrgChart' does not exist on type 'JQuery'`. Is it something with the way the jOrgChart.js code is written?

Full code is [here](https://github.com/dikuw/SVOrgChart).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add "declare var $;"
Replace "jQuery("#org").jOrgChart()" with "$("#org").jOrgChart()"

Answer (score 1):

You need to first ensure that jQuery is loaded and after that your plugin is loaded.

One way to fix it would be to add an external reference in the `config.json` file.

So, go to the `config > config.json` file and modify the `externals` section as below. Modify as per your path/folder structure. Just ensure that the file is accessible to end users:

```
 //standard code 
"externals": {
    // standard entries omitted for brevity
    "jquery": {
      "path": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js",
      "globalName": "jquery"
    },
    "jqueryui":{
        "path": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js",
        "globalName": "jquery"
        "globalDependencies": ["jquery"]
    }
    "jOrgChart": {
      "path": "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test/MyDocLib/Scripts/jOrgChart.js",
      "globalName": "jquery",
      "globalDependencies": ["jqueryui"]
    }
  },
 //standard code
```

Once done, go to your webpart typescript file and add the references as:

```
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
require('jqueryui');
require('jOrgChart');
```

After that you can call your `jQuery("#org").jOrgChart` method in either `render` method or any other custom method that you are using something like:

```
public render(): void {
    this.domElement.innerHTML = "<your html content>";

    jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
        jQuery("#org").jOrgChart({ chartElement: "#chart", dragAndDrop: false });
    });    
}
```

Reference - [Add jQueryUI to your webpart](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/add-jqueryui-accordion-to-web-part)

Update as per comments -

I see that you are using the drag and drop functionality. According to jQuery Org Chart plugin, if you need to use the drag-drop, then you need to add additional dependency on jQuery UI as well. So, first load the files in the order as `jQuery > jQueryUI > jQueryOrgChart`

Comment: I did have the externals in my json.config, so added that to the question. I've tried `require("jOrgChart");` and `import "jOrgChart";` but still I get `Property 'jOrgChart' does not exist on type 'JQuery'` as a typescript build error. Could it be an issue with the way the jOrgChart.js file is written?

Comment: have updated answer, can you check now ?

Comment: Thanks - same error with jQuery UI added (updated code above): `Property 'jOrgChart' does not exist on type 'JQuery'`

Comment: it needs to be `"jorgchart": {
    "path": "./Scripts/jOrgChart.js",
    "globalName": "jquery",
    "globalDependencies": ["jqueryui"]
}` in the dependencies. You are specifying `jquery`

Comment: Okay corrected that, still getting the same error but now getting "Property 'dialog' does not exist on type 'JQuery'" as well, which is part of jQuery UI so I must have broken something. Checking...

Comment: Okay. `$("#Dialog--Person").dialog` is good when I have `import "jqueryui";`. Still get the jOrgChart build error with `import "jorgchart";` or `require("jorgchart");`

Comment: hmm, can you check if the file ,`jquery org chart`, is actually loaded or not. Specify a location in SharePoint,  a folder in doc lib perhaps ?

Comment: maybe I'm missing something: this is a TypeScript build error before I even deploy to SharePoint Online...